# What's The Equilavent of PHP code: header() in Asp.Net?

Tags: php, asp.net, flash

I have a flash file that is loading data from XML file.
After I had a problem of reloading data, I found a solution to write XML code to screen with PHP code.
Here's the code I use:

```
<?php
header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");
echo '<images>';
echo '<image title="1" src="Images/01.jpg" description="1"/>';
echo '<image title="2" src="Images/02.jpg" description="2"/>';
echo '<image title="3" src="Images/03.jpg" description="3"/>';
echo '<image title="4" src="Images/04.jpg" description="4"/>';
echo '<image title="5" src="Images/05.jpg" description="5"/>';
echo '</images>';
?>
```

I want to use same skill in Asp.Net aspx page. I found `Response.Write()` as an equilavent to `echo` function but how can I convert `header()` functions to Asp.Net code?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add

HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader
```

Comment: These don't exist anymore in ASP.Net Core

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Response.ContentType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525208%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for the content type and you can also look into [Response.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.cache%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).SetExpires for expiring the cache immediately.